# Regular expression for all binary strings avoiding 0110

Tags: regular-expressions

Consider the language
$$ L = \{ w : w \in {0,1}^* \text{ and } w \text{ doesn't contain } 0110 \text{ as a substring.} \} $$
What is a regular expression for this language?

I thought of $1(1)^*0(0)^*$.
But this seemed to not contain any strings starting with $0$. If I do $1(1)^*0(0)^* | 0(0)^*1(1)^*$ then it can contain $0110$. How can I improve my answer to this question?

Comment: One mechanical way to do it: Construct a DFA that recognizes $\overline{L}$. Complement the set of final states and construct the regular expression associated with the resulting DFA.

Answer (score 1):

A string avoids $0110$ regardless of any initial or final $1$-runs, so we it suffices to consider strings starting and ending with $0$. We can write every such string as follows:
$$
0^{a_1} 1^{b_1} 0^{a_2} 1^{b_2} \cdots 0^{a_\ell},
$$
where $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\ldots,a_\ell \geq 1$. This string avoids $0110$ if $b_i \neq 2$ for all $i$.

The following infinite regular expression corresponds to the above:
$$
\epsilon + 0^+ + 0^+(1+111^+)0^+ + 0^+(1+111^+)0^+(1+111^+)0^+ + \cdots
$$
Here the first summand corresponds to the edge case $\ell = 0$. We can describe all of these cases using a single regular expression as follows:
$$ \epsilon + (0^+(1+111^+))^*0^+ $$
Bringing back the initial and final $1$-runs, this gives the following regular expression for your language:
$$ 1^* + 1^*(0^+(1+111^+))^*0^+1^* $$
Using some case analysis, we can simplify this into
$$ 1^*(0^+(1+111^+))^*0^*1^* $$